# jQuery callback on success function async issue

Tags: jquery, function, asynchronous, callback

I'm getting some XML via Ajax and processing it by calling a function on success.

From the success function (handleHousestark), I'm checking the XML and calling another function (getJonSnow) to add some extra data in. It all works fine if I set getJonSnow to async :false. Without that it doesn't work.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $( "#button" ).click(function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "test_php.php?function=getmain",
      cache: false,                           
      success: handleHousestark                       
    });
  });
});

function handleHousestark(html) {   
  var feature="";
  var xml = html;
  xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml );
  $xml = $( xmlDoc );

  $($xml).find( "features" ).children().each(function(index) {
    var attributevalue = $(this).attr('value');
    var attributeunittype = $(this).attr('type');     
    var attributecode = $(this).attr('code');  
    if(attributeunittype!="Valuelist") {
      feature=feature+"<B>"+attributevalue+"</B><BR/>";
    }

    if(attributeunittype=="Valuelist") {
      values = getJonSnow(attributecode,function(res) { 
        ///THIS WORKS WITH getJonSnow on async false, otherwise doesn't work.           feature=feature+"<B>"+res+"</B><BR/>";
      });
    }   
  }); 
  $("#content").html(feature);
}

function getJonSnow(attributecode,callback) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "test_php.php?function=getvalues",
    cache: false,     
    success:  callback                  
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that `$("#content").html(feature);` get executed before `feature=feature+"<B>"+res+"</B><BR/>";`.
Call to server needs time to get response back, if you don't put async to false, code below will execute before result come from http request.

Comment: I agree, is what i'm doing even possible without async:false? I feel my approach may just be wrong.

Comment: Maybe you can append elements to your content each time you recieve new data from http request.

Answer (score 0):

i ended up accomplishing this with await and async which worked really well. I hadn't done ajax in a few years and was a bit behind with the latest methodologies.

Sample below, i didn't test this sample but hopefully other people get the jist.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $( "#button" ).click(function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "test_php.php?function=getmain",
      cache: false                      
    })
    .done(function(data)
                        {

                            handleHousestark(data);

                        })  ;
  });
});

async function handleHousestark(html) {   
  var feature="";
  var xml = html;
  xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml );
  $xml = $( xmlDoc );

  $($xml).find( "features" ).children().each(function(index) {
    var attributevalue = $(this).attr('value');
    var attributeunittype = $(this).attr('type');     
    var attributecode = $(this).attr('code');  

    values=await getJonSnow(attributecode);

    if(attributeunittype!="Valuelist") {
      feature=feature+"<B>"+attributevalue+"</B>"+values+"<BR/>";
    }


    }   
  }); 
  $("#content").html(feature);
}

async function getJonSnow(attributecode) {

  const  tmp = $.ajax({
    url: "test_php.php?function=getvalues",
    cache: false               
  });

  return  tmp;
}
```